# Git stash pop error - Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge

Tags: git

I have the following error when i use `git stash pop`:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        user/h2oai_driver.py
        user/quantile_lift.R
        user/scratch.ipynb
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
The stash entry is kept in case you need it again.
```

I want to pop my changes from stash. But I don't need any changes in user/... files.
What should i do in this situation? (i have nothing to commit or stash so i can't follow the advice
`commit your changes or stash them before you merge`)

Answer (score 1):

> (i have nothing to commit or stash so i can't follow the advice `commit your changes or stash them before you merge`)

You *could* follow that advice, but it leads you down a rabbit hole, especially if you use `git stash` for this.  Stashing might let you pop the *other* stash, but then you have a new stash, and what will you do with that?  So, let's look at another option.

The reason `git stash pop` is complaining here is that the application of a stash—the `git stash apply` step<sup>1</sup>—involves running `git merge`.<sup>2</sup>  That *merge* operation is going to overwrite those three files.

> But I don't need any changes in user/... files.

Perhaps, by this, you mean: *After restoring the stashed changes, I'd like to discard the updated `user/...` files and put back the ones I had just before I ran `git stash pop`.*

If that *is* what you mean, then just *do that*.  For instance:

```
cd user
mkdir /tmp/save
cp h2oai_driver.py quantile_lift.R scratch.ipynb /tmp/save
git restore -s HEAD -SW h2oai_driver.py quantile_lift.R scratch.ipynb
```

This makes a place to save the three files, then uses `git restore` to undo your current changes, so that `git merge` can merge these three files.  Then:

```
git stash pop
```

This step merges into those three files, along with everything else that `git stash pop` does.  Then:

```
cp /tmp/save/* .
```

puts the three files back.  These commands all assume a Unix-like shell, of course; make any necessary alterations for whatever shell / CLI you use.

(Note: I am not an R or ipynb user, so I am not sure what this is all about here.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Remember, `git stash pop` just means `git stash apply && git stash drop`: do the apply first, and then if and only if the apply succeeds, drop the now-applied stash.

<sup>2</sup>Technically it runs `git merge-recursive` directly, rather than using `git merge`.  This is because the set of commits that *store* a stash are ... weird.  Stashes *are* commits, and this weirdness is one reason I actually recommend *avoiding* `git stash` if possible.  The `git stash` command is convenient, *when it works*, but when it gets you into corner cases, it can become extremely difficult to use.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach:

1. Unstage all local modifications
2. Run `git diff > /tmp/local-modifications.patch`
3. Run `patch -Rp1 < /tmp/local-modifications.patch` to remove all local changes
4. Pop the stash I want to pop
5. Run `patch -p1 < /tmp/local-modifications.patch` to restore the first set of changes

Look carefully at the output of the last `patch` to see how it conveyed conflicts (if any).

If you want full undo-ability of all of this, save a second patch file after step 4. Then reset your repo to a clean working tree and index, apply the second patch, stash those changes, then apply the first patch to restore your initial local changes.